# Translating an API post instruction to R httr

Tags: r, httr

I have been given the following POST instruction, and I am trying to translate it into httr:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://this.website.com/foldername>
    <input type="hidden" name="ExternalAction" value="AgetAscii">
    File Type <input type="text" name="filechar" value="0">
    <input type="submit" value="Click here to Retrieve the File"/>
</form>
```

I am having trouble getting the right syntax for httr. I would welcome suggestions. The initial input type, name and value seem straight forward, but I don't see how I bring the File Type arguments into httr, nor am I confident I am handling the final "submit" and value items properly.

I'd welcome suggestions.

Many thanks

Comment: Please include your current code and explain what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If I paste that example html into an local html file and substitute the action to be `http://bin.org/post` like so:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://httpbin.org/post">
  <input type="hidden" name="ExternalAction" value="AgetAscii">
  File Type <input type="text" name="filechar" value="0">
  <input type="submit" value="Click here to Retrieve the File"/>
</form>
```

Then the only form data reported back by httpbin.org as having been received are for `ExternalAction` and `filechar`. Therefore, to send this data via `httr::POST()` you would do:

```
library(httr)

action <- "https://this.website.com/foldername"

body <- list(ExternalAction = "AgetAscii", 
             filechar = "0")

POST(url = action, body = body)
```